# Where is that question about electricity and RAM?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I seem to remember a question (and answer) asking how often an electrical issue affects what is stored in RAM, and the answer was very high. Does anyone have a link to this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're thinking of the [cosmic rays question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580933/cosmic-rays-what-is-the-probability-they-will-affect-a-program) ([meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45620/program-errors-due-to-cosmic-rays)).